# MouseOver trigger doesn`t work after programmatically set Foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate

I'm new to WPF, but searching internet for some days I couldn't figure out my problem.

After I programmatically change `Foreground` property, `IsMouseOver` trigger doesn't work. Please be tolerant and thank in advance :)

```
<Style x:Key="ZizaMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Label FontSize="14"  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Name="ZizaMenuItemText" />
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ZizaMenuItemText" Property="Foreground" Value="#ff0000"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<StackPanel Height="30" Name="ZizaMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Label Content="ZIZA" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Height="25" Margin="20,0,10,0" />
  <Button Name="ZizaMenuInteresting" Click="ZizaMenuItemClicked" Content="ИНТЕРЕСНОЕ" Style="{StaticResource ZizaMenuItem}" />
  <Button Name="ZizaMenuBest" Click="ZizaMenuItemClicked" Content="ЛУЧШЕЕ" Style="{StaticResource ZizaMenuItem}" />
  <Button Name="ZizaMenuAuto" Click="ZizaMenuItemClicked" Content="АВТО" Style="{StaticResource ZizaMenuItem}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
private void ZizaMenuItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get label object from template
    Button zizaMenuItem = (Button)sender;
    Label zizaMenuItemText = (Label)zizaMenuItem.Template.FindName("ZizaMenuItemText", zizaMenuItem);
    // set Foreground color for all buttons in menu
    foreach (var item in ZizaMenu.Children)
      if (item is Button)
        ((Label)(item as Button).Template.FindName("ZizaMenuItemText", (item as Button))).Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    // set desired color to clicked button label
    zizaMenuItemText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(102, 206, 245));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is horrible code, *do not* mess with controls inside control templates, ever. `Template.FindName` is something only the control that is being templated should call internally to get its [parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx), and *only* those, everything else should be considered uncertain.

If you need to change a property template bind it, and then bind or set said property on the instance. In terms of [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you need to make sure not to create a **local value** which overrides the triggers (that is what you did). You can use a `Style` and `Setter` on the `Label` to bind the default `Foreground`.

```
<Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
    </Style>
</Label.Style>
```

Now you just need to set the `Foreground` of the `Button` itself, the `Trigger` should still internally have precedence over that `Setter`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with dependency property value precedence. Local values have higher precedence than template triggers.

For more information read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx